# Adafruit_SSD1306 and Adafruit-BBIO legacy install issues

Tags: raspbian, hat

trying to get my 0.91 oled v1.0 geekpi expansion board hat to run in general/autorun when powered on, the OLED and the Leds, however im having tis pp up everytime i get to the OLED , any help is greatly appreciated.

below the error code i will upload the code provided as well. im sure im breking some posting rule, but still i need the help.

**what was entered:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-pip -y
sudo pip3 install Adafruit_BBIO
```

**outcome:**

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Adafruit_BBIO
  Running setup.py clean for Adafruit_BBIO
Failed to build Adafruit_BBIO
Installing collected packages: Adafruit_BBIO
  Running setup.py install for Adafruit_BBIO ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for Adafruit_BBIO did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [56 lines of output]
      running install
      /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39
      copying Adafruit_I2C.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/Adafruit_BBIO
      copying Adafruit_BBIO/sysfs.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/Adafruit_BBIO
      copying Adafruit_BBIO/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/Adafruit_BBIO
      copying Adafruit_BBIO/Encoder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/Adafruit_BBIO
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/overlays
      copying overlays/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/overlays
      copying overlays/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/overlays
      running build_ext
      building 'Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DBBBVERSION41 -Isource/include/ -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c source/c_pinmux.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/c_pinmux.o -Wall
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DBBBVERSION41 -Isource/include/ -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c source/common.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/common.o -Wall
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DBBBVERSION41 -Isource/include/ -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c source/constants.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/constants.o -Wall
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DBBBVERSION41 -Isource/include/ -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c source/event_gpio.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/event_gpio.o -Wall
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DBBBVERSION41 -Isource/include/ -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c source/py_gpio.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/py_gpio.o -Wall
      source/py_gpio.c: In function ‘PyInit_GPIO’:
      source/py_gpio.c:602:4: warning: ‘PyEval_ThreadsInitialized’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        602 |    if (!PyEval_ThreadsInitialized())
            |    ^~
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:145,
                       from source/py_gpio.c:31:
      /usr/include/python3.9/ceval.h:129:36: note: declared here
        129 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyEval_ThreadsInitialized(void);
            |                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      source/py_gpio.c:603:7: warning: ‘PyEval_InitThreads’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        603 |       PyEval_InitThreads();
            |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:145,
                       from source/py_gpio.c:31:
      /usr/include/python3.9/ceval.h:130:37: note: declared here
        130 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(void) PyEval_InitThreads(void);
            |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/c_pinmux.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/common.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/constants.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/event_gpio.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/py_gpio.o -L/usr/lib -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/Adafruit_BBIO/GPIO.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
      /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:15: multiple definition of `version'; build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:15: first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:14: multiple definition of `both_edge'; build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:14: first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:13: multiple definition of `falling_edge'; build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:13: first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:12: multiple definition of `rising_edge'; build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:12: first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:11: multiple definition of `pud_down'; build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:11: first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:10: multiple definition of `pud_up'; build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:10: first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:9: multiple definition of `pud_off'; build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:9: first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:8: multiple definition of `alt0'; build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:8: first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:7: multiple definition of `output'; build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:7: first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:6: multiple definition of `input'; build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:6: first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:5: multiple definition of `low'; build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:5: first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:4: multiple definition of `high'; build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-uqo_ejwb/adafruit-bbio_1f73563c496c463e8beddc0488b7594c/source/constants.h:4: first defined here
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
      error: command '/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> Adafruit_BBIO

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: 1 DO NOT use apt-get use apt

Comment: 2 These warnings are common with python3.9 - indicating that the code has not been updated or tested. Contact the maintainer. Alternately use the Legacy OS.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I checked the source code. Some variables are defined in constants.h.

Every time constants.h file is included into c source file, memory area is assigned for those variables with names and linker finds that there are a lot of variables with the same name.

And THIS IS NOT ALLOWED in C, which is the error you see.